# Question about recovering the ring of an affine scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I am confused about a line in Vakil's algebraic geometry notes ([November 2017 version, page 136)](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/) right after he gives the definition of a scheme.

Suppose we have an affine scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. By definition, we have that $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is isomorphic to $(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A})$ for some ring $A$. Vakil states that we "may recover its ring (i.e. find the ring such that $\operatorname{Spec}A=X$) by taking the ring of global sections, as $X=D(1)$, so $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\Gamma(D(1),\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}) = A$ (as $D(1)=\operatorname{Spec}A$)."

My question is: why is the equality above an equality and not an isomorphism? By definition of an isomorphism of ringed spaces, we have a homeomorphism $\pi:\operatorname{Spec}A\rightarrow X$ and an isomorphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A}$, so don't we just get that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A})\cong A$? Perhaps the significance lies in the identification of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ with $D(1)$? If so, I am not sure how. What am I missing?

Second, Vakil goes on to say "we get more, and can 'recognize $X$ as the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}A':$ we get an isomorphism $\pi:(\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)})\rightarrow (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$." Does this follow from the above somehow?

Comment: Yes, it’s an isomorphism, albeit a very natural one, not an equality — so for most purposes, it can be treated as an equality. Some of algebraic geometry has a certain tendency to do this.

Comment: I would recommend you do Exercise II.2.4 in Hartshorne. If you are familiar with category-theoretical language, the exercise says that Spec (viewed as a functor on the opposite category of rings) is left adjoint to the global sections functor, which in particular implies that you can canonically identify $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ with $(\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X),\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)})$.

Comment: @Mindlack But then it seems very circular to me. You can recover the ring $A$ when you know which $A$ satisfies $\operatorname{Spec}A\cong X$.

Comment: @ponchan : What it says is that you can recover $A$ when you know that there is *some* $A$ satisfying $\mathrm{Spec}\,A \equiv X$. That's not really circular (although a lot of scheme theory does sound pretty circular when you stare at it too long without a break :) ).

Comment: @Nils Matthes: Just to be sure there isn't any misunderstanding: you mean that for any scheme $X$, there is a canonical (in particular, functorial in $X$) morphism $X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ which is an isomorphism for affine schemes. Correct?

Comment: @Mindlack: Correct. Note that I meant the morphism which corresponds to the identity map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ under the above adjunction. It doesn't get any more canonical than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ravi is being slightly informal. As in the comments, the correct statement is that there's a natural map coming from the adjunction between schemes and affine schemes and this natural map is an isomorphism.